# hadoop-connectors/gcsio - no message in exception

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

[GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcsio/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/gcsio/GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.java)

It looks like HttpResponseException is created without message.

```
  public static GoogleJsonResponseException createJsonResponseException(
      GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
    if (e != null) {
// ISSUE: HttpResponseException.Builder() constructor below doesn't set HttpResponseException.Builder.message.
//        HttpResponseException.Builder.message is passed to Throwable.detailMessage that is printed in Throwable.toString().
//        As a result, received from server exception doesn't print any information, it prints: null.
      return new GoogleJsonResponseException(
          new HttpResponseException.Builder(e.getCode(), e.getMessage(), responseHeaders), e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean `e.getMessage()` in the code returns null or an empty string?

Comment: Yes. I see this in stack trace.

Comment: Clarification, I see in stack trace "GoogleJsonResponseException: null"

Comment: Hi @SamMesh, Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: I think, in the snapshot above we have to add setMessaage():
new HttpResponseException.Builder(e.getCode(), e.getMessage(), responseHeaders).setMessage(<message for exception, probably, e.getMessage()>)

Comment: HI @SamMesh, Did you mean that the  e.getMessage() should return an error message?

Comment: I think, it makes sense to ask in appropriate place the question about package com.google.api.client.googleapis.json - "How to create GoogleJsonResponseException from GoogleJsonError". Probably, you could ask this question here in stackoverflow.com with tag google-cloud-platform.

Comment: Hi @SamMesh , since your actual question differs from the initial question, it would be best if you create a new StackOverflow thread, mentioning your issue/requirement.